# Does all Paths in a Swarm need to have the same fillColor?

Tags: paperjs

Im using Paper.js to create a Swarm of Circles.
Do they all have have the same fillColor?

```
var p = paper.Path.Circle({
      'center': [0,0],
      'radius': 20,
      'fillColor': 'red',
    });
var symbol = paper.Symbol(p);
for ( var i = 0; i < size; i ++ ) {
  var center = [0,0];
  var placed = symbol.place(center);
  placed.fillColor('#7FCAFF');
}
```

The fillColor is red anyway. If I do placed.scale() it works, but not editing the fillColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version, the fillColor of a placedSymbol is dependent on the fillColor of the Symbol itself.  The only values that you can change independently of the symbol definition are compositing values, such as opacity, scale, blend-mode, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. style seems to be part of the compositing values, at least it's [grouped with blendmode and opacity](http://paperjs.org/reference/item) which can be changed. And style has the property fillColor, but it can't be changed?

Comment: No, it can not be changed. A placed symbol does not have a fill or stroke color, but references that of the symbol's definition.