# Modifying Paperjs canvas example Moving Multiple Items

Tags: html, canvas, paperjs

On the Paperjs site, there is an example of Moving Multiple Items on this page http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/ The moving items are floating circles going left to right continuously. I am trying to modify this example to get the circles floating from the bottom to the top continuously. So far, I have managed to get them to float from the bottom to the top but for some reason, it is not continuous.

The other modification that I am trying to do with the example is to get the circles to have random colors based on a given array of colors. So far, the random color is only generated each time the page is refreshed and loaded.

1. How can I get the circles to float from bottom to top CONTINUOUSLY?
2. How can I get the circles to be randomly colored in the animation and not just on page load?

Here is my MODIFIED code:

```
// The amount of circles we want to make:
    var count = 50;

    /*random colors for circles*/
    var circleColors = new Array();
    circleColors[0] = "#2ab4e4";//BLUE
    circleColors[1] = "#a2a7a6";//GREY
    circleColors[2] = "#ef7047";//ORANGE
    circleColors[3] = "#ffffff";//WHITE
    /*end random colors for circles*/

    // Create a symbol, which we will use to place instances of later:
    var path = new Path.Circle({
        center: [0, 0],
        radius: 35,
        fillColor: circleColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * circleColors.length)]
    });

    var symbol = new Symbol(path);

    // Place the instances of the symbol:
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // The center position is a random point in the view:
        var center = Point.random() * view.size;
        var placedSymbol = symbol.place(center);
        placedSymbol.scale(i / count);
    }

    // The onFrame function is called up to 60 times a second:
    function onFrame(event) {
        // Run through the active layer's children list and change
        // the position of the placed symbols:
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

            // Move the item 1/20th of its width to the right. This way
            // larger circles move faster than smaller circles:
            item.position.y -= item.bounds.height / 20;

            // If the item has left the view on the right, move it back
            // to the left:
            if (item.bounds.bottom > view.size.height) {
                item.position.y = -item.bounds.height;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the ORIGINAL code from Paperjs:

```
// The amount of circles we want to make:
    var count = 150;

// Create a symbol, which we will use to place instances of later:
    var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: [0, 0],
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeColor: 'black'
    });

    var symbol = new Symbol(path);

// Place the instances of the symbol:
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // The center position is a random point in the view:
    var center = Point.random() * view.size;
    var placedSymbol = symbol.place(center);
    placedSymbol.scale(i / count);
    }

// The onFrame function is called up to 60 times a second:
    function onFrame(event) {
    // Run through the active layer's children list and change
    // the position of the placed symbols:
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

    // Move the item 1/20th of its width to the right. This way
    // larger circles move faster than smaller circles:
    item.position.x += item.bounds.width / 20;

    // If the item has left the view on the right, move it back
    // to the left:
    if (item.bounds.left > view.size.width) {
        item.position.x = -item.bounds.width;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the paper.js coordinate system is at the top left corner of the canvas. To put an item below the viewport's bounds, you need to add the view's height to that of the item.

```
if (item.bounds.bottom < 0) {
            item.position.y = view.size.height+item.bounds.height;
        }
```

As for random colors, you'll have to use pathItems, not placedSymbols to vary the color style across objects. Instead of this:

```
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: [0, 0],
    radius: 35,
    fillColor: circleColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * circleColors.length)]
});

var symbol = new Symbol(path);

// Place the instances of the symbol:
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // The center position is a random point in the view:
    var center = Point.random() * view.size;
    var placedSymbol = symbol.place(center);
    placedSymbol.scale(i / count);
}
```

You'll need something more like:

```
// Place the instances of the symbol:
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: Point.random() * view.size,
    radius: i / count,
    fillColor: circleColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * circleColors.length)]
});
```

See this post for details:
[Does all Paths in a Swarm need to have the same fillColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299670/does-all-paths-in-a-swarm-need-to-have-the-same-fillcolor)

Comment: Thank you. I understood the first part of your answer and changing that bit of code worked. Now my circles are floating continously. Thanks! However, I'm still a bit confused with the 2nd part of your answer in regards to pathItems and placedSymbols. How would I go about switching the symbols to path items?

Comment: As of yet there's no way to change a symbol to a pathItem. You'll just need to create paths instead of symbols in the first place.  See the edited answer above for the code.

This may run more slowly than using symbols, but this example seems to perform about as well as the original on my system.